# Create a continuous raster buffer for polyline

Tags: arcgis-desktop, distance, buffer

I would like to create a continuous raster that is a buffer around a polyline in ArcGIS.  For example, lets use a maximum buffer distance of 20m.

At a 20m distance from the line, the raster value would be 0;
At a 0m distance from the line (i.e. right on top) the raster value would be 1;
At a distance of 10m from the line, the raster value would be 0.5;
At a distance of 5.25m from the line, the raster value would be 0.2625;

I realize I could create multiple buffer polygons around the line, then convert to raster and normalize, but is there any easier way to do this that also allows for a more continuous raster?

Comment: Now that I reread your question, there is something it doesn't add up. I think the value at 5.25m should be 0.7375? In this case I should modify my answer and operate your raster using (20- RasterValue)/20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this in two steps.
First you need to create a raster with the distance to your line using the tool [Euclidean Distance](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/euclidean-distance.htm). This will create a raster from 0 to 20 (if you limit the distance to 20m).

And from here you can operate this raster using the [Raster Calculator](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/raster-calculator.htm) that in your case would be dividing your raster by 20.